# Wordpress wp-admin is not loading properly

Tags: wordpress

I have recently installed a wordpress site, but whenever I try to login to wp-admin , it is not loading properly, it is missing css and jquery files. I really don't have any idea about this. Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

In your Wordpress main folder find wp-config.php and look up:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

And set it to:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

This displays the errors for you to trace the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the all tables from database, and re-setup it again from browser step by step. May be then it will work fine.